# Android Studio "Edit Configuration" dialog doesn't fit into screen

Tags: android, android-studio

This might sound weird, that the edit configuration dialog is so big that it doesn't fit my screen and I can't access buttons and options at the bottom:

[image: Huge dialog]

I tried to resize it, but it doesn't let itself be resized or moved higher. Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel kinda stupid for not checking this before... But here is the solution:

### [image: Edit configurations in the dropdown menu]

Clicking that will get the same dialog in a scrollable and resizable format:
[image: Same dialog, scrollable and resizable]

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [Sizer](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer) may helps (I didn't try it but you can take a look at it)

> Sizer is a tiny freeware utility that gives you an easy and fast way to resize any window to an exact size. It could be a very useful tool for webmasters and web designers.

**EDIT :** Other possible solution you can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and write your own shortcut like this :

```
#=:: ; [Win]+[=]
    WinGet, window, ID, A
    InputBox, width, Resize, Width:, , 140, 130
    InputBox, height, Resize, Height:, , 140, 130
    WinMove, ahk_id %window%, , , , width, height
    return
```

Comment: Tried both.. they were unable the resize that dialogs height only the width.. but I found a better solution anyway so no problem